# Modify specific record from an array (method PUT)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have Model "user" and I have a model that includes an array of objects:

```
{users: [
 {
   id: 1,
   name: user1,
   status: new
 },
{
   id: 2,
   name: user2,
   status: new
 },
...
]}
```

But, I have to change the status of a single user. I try:

```
 actions: {
    checkAccept(id) {
      this.store.findRecord('user', id).then((record) => {
        record.set('status', 'accepted');
        record.save();
      });
 }
```

With the same method to remove the recording works if used record.DestroyRecord. Why  instead PUT method  sent GET ???

**UPDATED**
I'm using:

```
actions: {
 checkAccept(record) {
   this.store.adapterFor('userNetwork').updateRecord(this.store, this.userNetwork.type, record);
 }
}
```

but get this ERROR:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The `attr` method is not available on DS.Model, a DS.Snapshot was probably expected. Are you passing a DS.Model instead of a DS.Snapshot to your serializer
```

Comment: Is the record in your store when you do the findRecord call?

Comment: Specifically for one user does not exist. Only array of users in Store